# How to pass user input color into textcolor()?

Tags: c++, textcolor, turbo-c++, conio

How do I pass a user input color to the `textcolor()` function in `conio.h` ?

```
textcolor(BLUE);
cprintf("Hello");
```

works fine, but

```
char c[20];
gets(c);
textcolor(c);
cprintf("Hello");
```

throws an error. I didn't expect it to work myself. So the question is, how can a user enter a color for text to be displayed?
Due to some stupid constrains, I have to do this on the old turbo c++ and cannot use `graphics.h` , `dos.h` etc. So a solution that uses `textcolor()` itself would be great.

Comment: It's important to understand that `BLUE` is not a string, where the value read using `gets` is a string.  You need to convert that string to a value, perhaps using a lookup table, or a series of `if` statements.

Comment: Also, when code `throws an error`, include the error information in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will look something like this:

```
char c[20];
gets(c);

if (strcmp("BLACK",c) == 0) {textcolor(BLACK);}
else if (strcmp("BLUE",c) == 0) {textcolor(BLUE);}
else if ... more colors here ...

cprintf("Hello");
```

Remember the `BLUE` is not a string, it is a macro that equals the integer value of 1. `gets()` returns a string hence the `strcmp()` function.